# Spark views work initially, but then get a "Dynamic view compilation failed" error after 30 minutes or so

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

After pushing my asp.net mvc (with spark view engine) project to our live server yesterday I've started getting a strange error. Everything works fine initially, but after some time (maybe 30 minutes) the views start throwing "Dynamic view compilation failed" errors and complaining about namespaces not existing. The assemblies for the namespaces listed are in the bin (since it did work initially). I'm using the spark view engine on other websites running on the same box and have never seem this issue. What is causing these views to stop working?

Comment: There are mentions of a known race condition bug loading assemblies scattered here and there.  I've currently got an AppDomain very stubbornly throwing this error all the time, to the point where we are looking at redeveloping the front end of a whole site back in WebForms view engine.

Comment: I think I *finally* may have found the fix.  I am telling spark to load the assemblies I've had trouble with by calling .AddAssembly("fullnameToAssembly") on the SparkSettings we setup in our MvcApplication class.  I would guess this could also be done in _global.spark (since the namespace references can be setup in both places) or maybe even web.config (under a spark section).  It's been working all day, whereas before I could trigger the error quite consistently with an App pool recycle.

Comment: Don't ask me why only certain assemblies need this, though.  =p

Comment: This is great stuff qstarin, a really tough one to track down. Glad it's working for you!

Comment: I should update.  After we seemed to have it resolved (I *swear* it worked for most of a day), we started to receive a security exception relating to LinkDemands.  In the google group thread a security exception was mentioned and a hack around given, but it did not solve our exception.  We weren't able to figure it out and we've decided as a company to no longer use Spark for anything.  Thankfully, this site we were using it on is under re-development, so it wasn't too much extra work to revert back to WinForms engine (we decided not to go Razor/MVC3 just yet, too early still).

Comment: I should note that is on .Net v4.  We didn't receive the security exception when the project targeted .Net v3.5, and as far as we know the .AddAssembly will resolve the problem this question is about on earlier framework versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As qstarin mentioned, recycling the AppPool does seem to kick the assemblies out.  Here's the original Spark discussion regarding the issue:

http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/dbee06a0d1b2766f#

In general, it seems the issue is caused by Spark trying to compile the views BEFORE the AppPool has had time to load all of the assemblies.

Picking the assemblies one-by-one still seemed to cause random glitches for me, so I tweaked the code in that discussion post and load it as the first line in Application_Start(). Since then, I've pushed out a dozen or so applications over time and haven't seen the precompile issue once.

```
private void PreLoadAssemblies()
{
    // Deal with the compiling issue with Spark.
    var initialAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
    var files = di.GetFiles("*.dll");
    foreach (var fi in files)
    {
        var found = false;
        //already loaded? 
        foreach (var asm in initialAssemblies)
        {
            var a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fi.FullName);
            if (asm.FullName == a.FullName)
                found = true;
        }

        if (!found)
            Assembly.LoadFrom(fi.FullName);
    }
}
```

and then your Application_Start():

```
protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PreLoadAssemblies();
    base.Application_Start(sender, e);

    //Whatever else you normally do in Application_Start():
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
    ViewEngineManager.Configure(ViewEngines.Engines);
    RouteManager.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    new InjectionManager().StartNinject();
}
```