# Spark View Engine site works for about 30 minutes then gets a "Dynamic view compilation failed." error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

First off, this may be a duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892891/spark-views-work-initially-but-then-get-a-dynamic-view-compilation-failed-erro" but the answer to that question has not solved my issue.

My issue is the same with the linked question but the answer in question is not working. I was wondering if anyone has come across another solution that works for them that is not the same as the previous questions answer.

This is the error that is displayed:

> Dynamic view compilation failed. (0,0): error CS0518: Predefined type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported
>   c:\Code\XXXX\src\XXXX.Web\Views\Shared\application.spark(27,18):
>   error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic
>   expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?
>   c:\Code\XXXX\src\XXXX.Web\Views\Shared\application.spark(27,45):
>   error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic
>   expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?